# Fill date into columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have table:

| user_id | date | days_since_install |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 01-01-2021 | 0 |
| 001 | 02-01-2021 | 1 |
| 001 | 02-01-2021 | 2 |

It is necessary to check if there is "1" in the column "days_since_install" in grouping by use_id and if so, fill in True in the column "retention_1d" otherwise False.

The resulting table should look like this:

| user_id | retention_1d |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | True |
|  |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to get the first install per group, then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map it per user_id:

```
# get first install value (if you have duplicates you would need to get the min)
d = df[df['event_type'].eq('install')].groupby(df['user_id'])['date'].first()

# map the values per user_id
df['install'] = df['user_id'].map(d)
```

output:

```
   user_id event_type        date     install
0        1    install  01-01-2021  01-01-2021
1        1      login  02-01-2021  01-01-2021
2        1      login  04-01-2021  01-01-2021
```

As a one liner:

```
df['install'] = df['user_id'].map(df[df['event_type'].eq('install')]
                                    .groupby(df['user_id'])['date'].first())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` with filtered `install` without duplicates by `user_id`:

```
df['install'] = (df['user_id'].map(df[df['event_type'].eq('install')]
                                        .drop_duplicates('user_id')
                                        .set_index('user_id')['date']))
print (df)

   user_id event_type        date     install
0        1    install  01-01-2021  01-01-2021
1        1      login  02-01-2021  01-01-2021
2        1      login  04-01-2021  01-01-2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there case one id installs multiple times?
then use `groupby` + `ffill`

```
(df
.assign(install=df['date'].where(df['event_type'] == 'install'))
.assign(install=lambda x: x.groupby('user_id')['install'].ffill())
```

output:

```
user_id event_type  date    install
0   1   install 01-01-2021  01-01-2021
1   1   login   02-01-2021  01-01-2021
2   1   login   04-01-2021  01-01-2021
```